# Passing multiple variable using compact in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have a function which return the view with multiple variable. The code is

**HomeController.php**

```
public function profilePage(){
        $data = User::all();
        $book = Library::all();
        return view('page.profile' , compact(array('data', 'book')));
}
```

**profile.blade.php**

```
@include('layouts.sidebar')
.
.
.
 @foreach($book as $Library)
     <tr>
        <td>{{$Library->book}}</td>
        <td>{{$Library->name}}</td>
        <td>{{$Library->author}}</td>
        <td>{{$Library->price}}</td>
    </tr>
 @endforeach
```

**sidebar.blade.php**

```
<div class="info">
  <a href="{{ url ('profile' , $data -> first())}}" class="d-block">{{Auth::user() -> name }}</a>
</div>
```

When i try to refresh the browser to see the changes. It'll show error "undefined variable $book"

> Illuminate\ Foundation\ Bootstrap \ HandleExceptions: 176 handleError

on line

> addLoop($currentLoopData); foreach($currentLoopData as $Library): $env->incrementLoopIndices(); $loop = $env->getLastLoop(); ?>

Before i added the module to retrieve the data from **Library**, the code just work fine. So is this the correct approach to pass multiple variable into view?

Comment: You say "undefined variable $book", are you sure this is in profile.blade?

Comment: yes the function is to view on the profile.blade

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use this instead, and make sure you are loading the correct blade file, in your case, it's `profile.blade.php` inside the page folder.

```
public function profilePage(){
    $data = User::all();
    $book = Library::all();

    return view('page.profile', [
        'data' => $data,
        'book' => $book,
    ]);

}
```

Comment: Thanks, this code running well. But its seems like my approach is pretty similar as the solution?

Comment: You're welcome, I didn't quite understand this though "But its seems like my approach is pretty similar as the solution?"

Answer (score 0):

There are 4 ways for passing data to view:

1 -

```
 return view('page.profile' , ['book' => $book, 'data' => $data]);
```

2 -

```
return view('page.profile' , compact('book', 'data'));
```

3 -

```
return view('page.profile')
    ->with('data' => $data)
    ->with('book' => $book);
```

4 - Not recommended

```
return view('page.profile' , get_defined_vars());
```

Comment: Great! however, for me `get_defined_vars()` is not recommended at all. I would make the #3 to be `->with('data' => $data)->with('book' => $book);`